# Compiling GDAL 2.1.1 on CentOS 7

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, centos7, gdal

I'm trying to compile GDAL 2.1.1 on CentOS 7 but I've some troubles.

My compiling instructions are the following:

```
cd "/tmp"
tar xzf gdal-2.1.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.1.1

sed -i.bak 's/  char \\*type_name/  const char \\*type_name/g' /tmp/gdal-2.1.1/swig/php/gdal_wrap.cpp

unset ORACLE_HOME
export PY_INST_DIR=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export MAKEFLAGS="-j2"

./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local \
    --with-threads \
    --with-geos=/usr/bin/geos-config \
    --with-libz \
    --with-static-proj4=no \
    --with-php \
    --with-python=/bin/python \
    --with-libtiff \
    --with-geotiff=/usr/lib64/libgeotiff.so \
    --with-png=/usr \
    --with-gif=/usr \
    --with-jpeg=/usr \
    --with-curl \
    --with-pg=/usr/bin/pg_config \
    --with-ecw=/usr/local \
    --with-libkml=/usr/local \
    --with-libkml-lib=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-libkml-inc=/usr/local/include/kml \
    --with-mongocxx=/usr/local \
    --with-boost-lib-path=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-xml2=/usr/bin \
    --with-oci \
    --with-oci-include=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 \
    --with-oci-lib=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib \
    --with-spatialite=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-sqlite3=/usr/local/lib \
    --with-libjson-c=internal

make && make install
```

When I compile I obtain the following ....

```
...
....
checking for XTIFFClientOpen in -lgeotiff... no
checking for XTIFFClientOpen in -lgeotiff... (cached) no
STDERR: /bin/sh: ./config.rpath: No such file or directory
configure: error: We require at least GeoTIFF 1.2.1. Consider using the one supplied with GDAL
GNUmakefile:2: GDALmake.opt: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `config.status', needed by `GDALmake.opt'.  Stop.
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170904-6904-1shld0w" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170904-6904-1shld0w" returned 2

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/gdal_install_csi/recipes/inst_gdal.rb

 57: bash 'build-and-install-gdal' do
 58:   user "root"
 59:
 60:   code <<-EOH
 61:     cd "/tmp"
 62:     tar xzf gdal-#{version}.tar.gz
 63:     cd gdal-#{version}
 64:
 65:     sed -i.bak 's/  char \\*type_name/  const char \\*type_name/g' /tmp/gdal-#{version}/swig/php/gdal_wrap.cpp
 66:
 67:     unset ORACLE_HOME
 68:     export PY_INST_DIR=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 69:     export MAKEFLAGS="-j2"
 70:
 71:     ./configure \
 72:         --prefix=#{prefix_dir} \
 73:         --with-threads \
 74:         --with-geos=/usr/bin/geos-config \
 75:         --with-libz \
 76:         --with-static-proj4=no \
 77:         --with-php \
 78:         --with-python=/bin/python \
 79:         --with-libtiff \
 80:         --with-geotiff=/usr/lib64/libgeotiff.so \
 81:         --with-png=/usr \
 82:         --with-gif=/usr \
 83:         --with-jpeg=/usr \
 84:         --with-curl \
 85:         --with-pg=/usr/bin/pg_config \
 86:         --with-ecw=#{prefix_dir} \
 87:         --with-libkml=#{prefix_dir} \
 88:         --with-libkml-lib=#{prefix_dir}/lib \
 89:         --with-libkml-inc=#{prefix_dir}/include/kml \
 90:         --with-mongocxx=#{prefix_dir} \
 91:         --with-boost-lib-path=#{prefix_dir}/lib \
 92:         --with-xml2=/usr/bin \
 93:         --with-oci \
 94:         --with-oci-include=#{oracle_include} \
 95:         --with-oci-lib=#{oracle_lib} \
 96:         --with-spatialite=#{prefix_dir} \
 97:         --with-sqlite3=#{prefix_dir} \
 98:         --with-libjson-c=internal
 99:
100:     make && make install
101:   EOH
102:
103:   not_if { ::File.exists?(install_path) }
104: end
105:

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/gdal_install_csi/recipes/inst_gdal.rb:57:in `from_file'

bash("build-and-install-gdal") do
  action [:run]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  command "build-and-install-gdal"
  backup 5
  returns 0
  user "root"
  code "    cd \"/tmp\"\n    tar xzf gdal-2.1.1.tar.gz\n    cd gdal-2.1.1\n\n    sed -i.bak 's/  char \\*type_name/  const char \\*type_name/g' /tmp/gdal-2.1.1/swig/php/gdal_wrap.cpp\n\n    unset ORACLE_HOME\n    export PY_INST_DIR=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages\n    export MAKEFLAGS=\"-j2\"\n\n    ./configure         --prefix=/usr/local         --with-threads         --with-geos=/usr/bin/geos-config         --with-libz         --with-static-proj4=no         --with-php         --with-python=/bin/python         --with-libtiff         --with-geotiff=/usr/lib64/libgeotiff.so         --with-png=/usr         --with-gif=/usr         --with-jpeg=/usr         --with-curl         --with-pg=/usr/bin/pg_config         --with-ecw=/usr/local         --with-libkml=/usr/local         --with-libkml-lib=/usr/local/lib         --with-libkml-inc=/usr/local/include/kml         --with-mongocxx=/usr/local         --with-boost-lib-path=/usr/local/lib         --with-xml2=/usr/bin         --with-oci         --with-oci-include=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64         --with-oci-lib=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib         --with-spatialite=/usr/local         --with-sqlite3=/usr/local         --with-libjson-c=internal\n\n    make && make install\n"
  interpreter "bash"
  declared_type :bash
  cookbook_name "gdal_install_csi"
  recipe_name "inst_gdal"
  not_if { #code block }
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

I've tried to search on the web for the error

```
STDERR: /bin/sh: ./config.rpath: No such file or directory
    configure: error: We require at least GeoTIFF 1.2.1. Consider using the one supplied with GDAL
```

but no useful information found. What about config.rpath?

Note that I've installed GeoTIFF 1.4.1 on my system

Are there some dependecies that i don't use?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can find links to repositories for different os here
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries